# How can i get text field instead of <select> input for ManyToManyField relation?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-forms

This is the model relation:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    tagfield = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s,%s' % (self.title,self.content)


class PostModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post


class PostModelFormNormalUser(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        exclude = ('user', 'created', 'modified')
```

in views.py:

```
        form = PostModelFormNormalUser()
        context = {'form':form}
        return render_to_response('addpost.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

in add.html: `{{ form.as_p }}

The title,content and select input is being displayed in webpage.

```
<p><label for="id_tagfield">Tagfield:</label> <select multiple="multiple" name="tagfield" id="id_tagfield">
</select> <span class="helptext"> Hold down "Control", or "Command" on a Mac, to select more than one.</span></p>
```

How can i get textbox instead of  input for `name = models.CharField(max_length=100)`.

Tag.name would be string seperated by spaces. I need to 'title,content,tagname' to display on webpage.

Comment: Try for widget
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/widgets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets

You'll want something like this:

```
class PostModelFormNormalUser(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        exclude = ('user', 'created', 'modified')
        widgets = {
            'tagfield': Textinput(),
        }
```

Then you'll need to handle the POST data yourself in the view.